# I am trying to make my SCNNode rotate but I cannot seem to get it to work

Tags: swift, scenekit, scnnode

My `SCNNode` is a compass that I want to rotate towards north.

```
compassNode = scene?.rootNode.childNodes[0]
```

I am successfully getting heading data and converting it to radians and storing it in a variable called angle.

```
angle = newHeading.trueHeading.toRadians
```

I have tried three methods now:

```
rotate = SCNAction.rotate(by: CGFloat(angle), around: SCNVector3(0, 1, 0), duration: 0.5)
compassNode?.runAction(rotate)
```

and

```
compassNode?.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, Float(angle))
```

and

```
let oldTransform = compassNode?.transform
let newTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(Float(angle), 0, 1, 0)
SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 0.5
compassNode?.transform = SCNMatrix4Mult(newTransform, oldTransform!)
SCNTransaction.commit()
```

None of them makes any noticeable transformation to the compass. It appears to be still.

Comment: Some suggestions: Sure compassNode is child[0]?  Change its position x+10 or something, make sure it moves.  Try hardcoding the angle value - make sure it's doing what u think it should.  Try spinning it in place first, before rotating around something

Comment: @Voltan I was able to change its position by changing the x value. Because when I created the scene I used the file that was the compass model as the scene so it should be child[0] in the list of things in the scene. Essentially I do want the compass to just spin. I just figured rotating around the y axis is the same thing as spinning?

Comment: Ok, then the node is good.  I do think 'around' works, but it could depend on pivot point of the node and also if the model starts with the right rotation (I can provide a link for how to do that), but that's why I suggested hard coding the angle, so that at 90 degrees, ur sure that it points to spot you think it should, then you can back into the math problems.

Comment: @Voltan How can I hard code it to point at 90 degrees? Also I think I might have a problem with the pivot point. I believe it might be not dead center of the compass and a little bit between there and the needle.

Answer (score 0):

Running out of comment characters...  Sry - have to put it in answer section.

Convert 90 degrees to radians, rotateTo that value.  Rotating models can be confusing in 3D (for me anyway), sometimes it's easier to just use an SCNBox at first - it will have the correct rotation by default provided you're looking down -Z if you didn't change the camera view.  You can turn on the the 3D outlines and sometimes that helps provide a better visual OR just texture map the box with different colors so that Red is the top, Green is front or whatever.

Then you can reshape the box, rotated it with different angles until you get the hang of rotateTo, rotateBy, rotateAround.  I'm not a math guru, so unfortunately trial and error for me sometimes, but once I understand what's happening, then I can put the model in and know that my math works - then if I have to do some work on the model, such as pivot point or need to change the model - set Z-UP or whatever (this post: 59766878), then I'm focused on one thing at a time and not having a combination of problems to figure out.

I've also used lookAt and placed various (hidden) nodes at particular positions, so that I can see what X,Y,Z rotations look like at various points in a game and from different view points.

Comment: I mean can't rotate it by any amount. I tried rotating it 180 degrees which is just pi in radians and it does not move. I haven't found a method that works yet. and its not like the compass is symmetrical and I just wouldn't know if it moved. The side that is meant to be facing north is intentionally longer and has an arrowhead on the end.

Comment: Let's slow it down and see what happens: vRotate1 = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(450)), z: 0, duration: 3)

Comment: so I tried that and did compassNode?.runAction(vRotate1) and nothing happened

Comment: Ok, what does your render loop look like - RU using SCNSceneRendererDelegate?

Comment: Change ? to ! - force it, if it crashes ur node is not right

Comment: Other than that, if you can share your code in Github, I might be able to fix it for u

Comment: I'm using func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading). I do have a SCNSceneRendererDelegate that I was using for testing. I changed ? to ! and it doesn't crash

Comment: What I'm looking for is any movement at all on the screen, because I use that rotation in a bunch of games, so I know it works.  Since I can't see ur code or screen, I'm just guessing.  Can you create a node and just create a runAction to move it back and forth across the screen just so we have some activity?

Comment: If might be Swift and how you setup variables and declarations, if you are new that that